# Clearcase error while merging code

Tags: clearcase

I am not able to merge the code in regression branch for a specific package

[image]

The error is:

```
merge: Error: *** No Automatic Decision Possible
merge: Error: *** Aborting...
merge: Error: Unable to remove "C:\TEMP\tmp22349": Permission denied.
Directory merges were necessary and -depth was specified
Unable to evaluate all possible merge candidates
```

How to avoid this error?

please find attached screen for error.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "`Unable to remove "C:\TEMP\tmp22349": Permission denied.`", launch a [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) the process which keeps an handle on that resource: kill that or those processes.

Then delete the file. And try the merge -abort one more time.