# Unable to create Index.lock no such file or directory | GitHub Desktop Windows

Tags: github, github-for-windows

[image: error]

I have no idea why this problem is happening when I try to clone a GitHub fork. This problem happens with other forks as well.

Comment: Here is another post that answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and create one manually.

If you can't (create it manually), that could highlight a permission issue, which would explain why it was not created by Git in the first place.

As the [OP zuckonit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10081833/zuckonit) mention [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52108282/index-lock-missing-for-gtihub-desktop/52108583?noredirect=1#comment91196101_52108583):

> I fixed it: If I disable ransomware protection on my PC, everything is fixed.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/TEQ6T91.png]

Comment: I'm starting to think this is an issue with GitHub desktop. Even when I change branch, I get a big error. ([here is a snip of the error](https://i.imgur.com/laCGKHu.png))

Comment: @zuckonit check there is no other process running on those files: as a test, try changing branch just after having rebooted (to minimize the processes). Check also the embeded Git version: only Git 2.19 will mitigate that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755262/6309

Comment: How would I check what processes are running on those files? I ran `git gc --auto` and it did nothing to resolve the issue.

Comment: @zuckonit https://stackoverflow.com/a/34702821/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/31918643/6309: search for "gh00": that will give you all processes with an open handle on those files.

Comment: Process explorer found nothing.

Comment: I will also like to point out that the [index.lock file is missing.](https://i.imgur.com/RGbAKWv.png)

Comment: @zuckonit in that case, Git itself must have locked those files because of a git gc (as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755262/6309). Git 2.19 will teach git gc to release properly those files.

Comment: Can you try, still using GitHub Desktop, to type first `git config --global gc.auto 0` (in any folder you want) (see in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28092576/6309). Then check if the issue persists.

Comment: No matter what I do with github desktop [I still get errors.](https://i.imgur.com/79nFmTR.png) I deleted a repo and then cloned it from github and I get a new error.

Comment: @zuckonit Did you type the `git config --global gc.auto 0` first?

Comment: @zuckonit For testing, can you try and run GitHub Desktop as admin?

Comment: I fixed it. [If I disable ransomware protection on my PC, everything is fixed.](https://i.imgur.com/TEQ6T91.png)

Comment: @zuckonit Great, well done! I have included your comment and picture in the answer for more visibility.